# A folder with name 'html already exists In IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9GKc.png
Firstly, I new a project called html. Then I delete the whole directory.
After a time, I want to use this name again. But it shows me this error. It seems directly delete the whole directory can't delete project thoroughly.
I search the Internet about this question. They mention jira settings, but I don't know what it means.

Comment: Please show the structure of your project on the filesystem. Are you sure HTML directory does not exist?

Comment: yes, I delete html directory ago. Then I want to use the same name to create a new project, but it displays file exists.

Comment: Share the structure of the project on the file system.

Comment: https://pic1.zhimg.com/80/v2-1fada8f00723f73e3aa193bdd58dabdd_1440w.png  this is my file structure

Comment: So, the html folder is still here.

Comment: no html folder is here. My name just contain Html and html-test. These names are not same with html

Comment: Windows filesystem is not case-sensitive. HTML and html are the same names for it.

Comment: wow, it's true. Thank you for solving my question.